# How to compare (sort) GregorianCalendar in Java

Tags: java, sorting, date

I have class:

```
public class LoginLog implements Serializable, Comparable<LoginLog> {
     private String ip;
     private Calendar  calendar ;

     public LoginLog( String ip) {
        this.calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    //get and set.....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LoginLog o) {
        return getCalendar().compareTo(o.getCalendar());
    }
}
```

I have `ArrayList` of this object...

Sort:
`Collections.sort(list);`

Sort output:

`11:31 09-02-2016
11:09 09-02-2016
10:56 09-02-2016
10:36 09-02-2016
11:29 09-02-2016
10:48 09-02-2016
15:02 08-02-2016`

That... it's not correct sorting.

It ranks only by day...

**NOTE:** I am ussing `pattern="HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"`

Where is a problem?

**Update 1:**

```
    Set<LoginLog> loginLogSet = //load data from db
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(loginLogSet);
    Collections.sort(list);
    loginLogSet = new HashSet<LoginLog>(list);
    //send data using HttpServletRequest to page and print using foreach
```

Comment: I think you issue may be somewhere else, since the documentation for `Calendar` states, “Compares the time values (millisecond offsets from the Epoch) represented by two Calendar objects”, and that should be the correct order. Can you show us the code where you are creating your list and sorting it?

Comment: @Veluria Thank you for your reply. I update my post.

Comment: Well, there you go. A HashSet isn't sorted. Try `TreeSet` instead, for example.

Comment: @nustauos I do not see that you are using any date time information taken from the database. you are creating a GregorianCalendar for each LoginLog object. May I know why you do that?

Comment: @Diyoda When I read data from database, I read object, because I am using `ORM`.

Comment: But why are you instantiating GregorianCalendar for each LoginLog in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The `HashSet` data structure doesn't guarantee the ordering of the added items. When you add the sorted list to the newly created `HashSet`, they will get shuffled again.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you sort your list if you just put it back in your original set afterwards, because a `HashSet` isn't sorted, and it will have the same, "random" order it had before. If you want a sorted set, you could use `TreeSet` instead. And a `TreeSet` is always sorted, so you don't need to sort it beforehand as long as the class properly implements `Compareable`.

For example, the following code

```
List l = Arrays.asList("Hallo", "1", "Fünfzehn");
Set<String> s = new TreeSet(l);
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
[1, Fünfzehn, Hallo]
```